# UIBarButtonItem active mouse area

Tags: ios, ios5

I have used two uibarbuttonitems and added a flexible style between them to adjust them at left and right. But when I click just near the buttons the respective actions are got called, even I don't click on the button (here fox example I clicked approx 20px before the right bar button). can any one explain why the action is performed when i click outside of the button not inside it. I check it with custom uitoolbar also and it is show the same problem.

Comment: consider that these elements are used on touch devices and your finger is not as precise as your mouse ;)

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @mak: there is no need of code! question is enough explanatory!!! and kanika go with Engin's answer. I also found this when I did same thing as you.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa-Touch controls usually have larger active touch areas than they are visible on screen. Especially with bar buttons, the touch area can be dynamically enlarged if there are no other bar buttons nearby.